# Tips on creating a custom view layout for a diagram

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I need to create an algorithm to layout some hierarchical data but have never done this kind of thing before and need some broad tips.

Basically I need to recreate this diagram (with dynamic data):

[diagram http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15126868/diagram.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15126868/diagram.png)
[bigger](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15126868/diagram.png)

I don't have a problem with most of it but need help with two things:

1. How do I approach writing a layout algorithm?
2. Should I use UIView subclasses for all discs or use quartz (I do need interaction)

Any suggestions most welcome. I don't need too much detail.

---

A bit more detail:

I'm currently thinking I should use UIView subclasses and layoutSubviews. Trouble is I need to know the size (at least roughly) of all nodes before I can start to position them. Then, as the positioning involves rotation, I may need to adjust child positioning again - and I can't add labels until after any rotation.

Other considerations seem to be: that the presentation area is rectangular, not square; that I can't spill off the page; and that I will need to animate changes to the sizes of the discs.

Any pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing is very difficult.

Interestingly the perhaps main actual initial constraint here is the size of the typography.

In the example given: Observe they could have chosen a different SCPT** somewhat larger (perhaps, 10%-15% larger) or somewhat smaller ***and it would have still worked***. They made an aesthetic decision on the SCPT.

***White space is critical to design***. Their particular graphic designer happened to like the particular feel of white space which you see. But it would have by no means been "wrong" with a smaller SCTP. Further, observe they could have used an even larger SCPT ... IF ... they used a smaller point size on the typography.

Note that in any event you simply ***won't be able to display that much type*** that small on an iPad (or Fone4).

So straight away you have to make decisions about how the type will appear, popup, audio or whatever.  Even the white type ("on the discs" type) will give you trouble.

You will have to do lots of tests with photoshop first on to your iPad before even proceeding with an algorithm.  So purely for what it's worth...

Here's how I personally would do this sort of thing.  In general plan: ***I would try to do a squishy algorithm that retries itself until it finds a result it is happy with.***

IMHO, based on previously doing this type of thing: ***this problem is too hard to get it done in one go with some particularly smart-ass heuristic***.  Since there is no one smart-ass heuristic that will save the day, I'd do this:

1) calculate the total trillions to display.  (it looks like about 2.5 is the total in the example image)

2) guess a SCPT value to begin with.  what about for example "18" based on the actual image at the screen size we see above as posted inside your question.

3) put the big one (sun) in the dead center, and for the middle ones (planets) -- just choose a very easy heuristic, what about from biggest to smallest going anticlockwise srtaing at the top left (don't try to get clever than that with that part of the problem - which indeed could be a huge research project purely on it's own) .. and do the same with the small ones (moons).

4) for the sticks between planets and moons - ***adopt a trivial solution*** (like "always 0.5 cm"!!) and that's that.  with AI you gotta cut your losses .. everywhere!  :)  ***Fix the moons to the planets and forget about them***.

5) Now a hard part .. run some sort of heuristic over them ***that evenly balances*** what you have so far.  ***treat color as mass and no color as no mass and move the "sun"*** until it is balancedish.  (to be clear, as an example that would be likely downwards if you followed the "planet" layout mentioned in 3.) maybe also move all the planet/moon systems in-out to try to balance it.

6) ***next the iteration.  look at that result and decide if you like it!  go back to (2) and pick a new value.*** (maybe "16!" for example)

(7) there are two possible outcomes here.  ***it might be that during development, there is one magic value for SCPT that always works.***  perhaps "14.3" or "18.2" or whatever.  ***if you find such a value, never tell anyone.  keep it as your own secret information!!!!***  milk it for everything it is worth with clients. conversely and more difficultly, you might find you need a different value each time. in that case: your AI will have to on it's own iterate through values until ***it finds one it likes***.  (for example, by determining whether all your labels fit or not .. and obvious things like "are they touching" "all on screen" etc.)

Anyway FWIW (perhaps nothing) that is what I would do - an iterative approach based on a first guess for the SCPT.

Incidentally: you may well want to buy and study the classic and brilliant book on this sort of display of information!!!  Everyone should have a copy.

Tufte's ***The visual display of Quantatative Information***
by Edward R. Tufte
ISBN 0961392142

Regarding the mechanics of laying out the image. You should use quartz or any other low-level drawing - forget about UIViews and the like.  You should surely completely separate the logic from the drawing layer, so (even if you do want to change to UIViews, OpenGLES, or whatever) it's only changing a few lines of code.

Hope it helps somehow.

Notes...
** SCPT .. square centimeters per trillion

Followup...
"To keep the logic separate would you use a manager-type pattern?"
To be honest: if I was doing it, I would just start a whole new app purely for the "research" of getting this part, this challenge, working right.  In that app (to be honest!) I would make bugger all effort to do anything in any tidy manner whatsoever!  :-/ Globals everywhere!  :)   Unfortunately for me I can only think of the one thing at a time, so at that stage I would only be thinking about the algorithm, per se.

I believe, once you cracked the problem per se, once you came to implement it in a bigger project ... really, FWIW, if it was me, I'd simply make it a class (let's say AmazingClass) nothing more complicated than that. Personally I would set the data somewhere separately (whether in a DB or just an array or whatever) and I would just let the AmazingClass take care of getting the data, even.  (My thinking - you never know how the hell you're going to need the data and when, at what point in the process of AmazingClass.  So, just give up and let AmazingClass take it as and when it wants it.)

If you are familiar with these awesome-sounding manager-patterns of which you speak - yeah, why not!  In short I would heavily separate it out as much as possible. I'm not good enough to speak on the best way to do that - but just completely separate it out somewhere. Sorry I can't help on that one.

Comment: Joe, what an awesome answer, thank you. It's all really useful info. I was thinking of something along the lines of a SCPT & I'm *really* glad you think an iterative approach I'd needed - I was starting to think I was a simpleton because I couldn't figure out a way to process the layout in one sweep.

Comment: To keep the logic separate would you use a manager-type pattern? It's going to be a tough one as I suspected but you've set me off in a good direction. A big thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Agreed. An initial mess in the name of research seems best. I haven't played with CA & CG very much so I'll start there I think, then see if I can get something vaguely working without the text. Thanks again Joe - I'm feeling good now!

Comment: Animating the process is a cracking idea. I will want to animate changes to the layout anyway so might as well. No perl for me though - I never learnt it so I'd better stick with C. I've added my twitter id to my profile if you're interested in seeing how it goes. Again, big thanks.